# htaccess to redirect to a different site with a query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I am trying to redirect:
`http://example.com/sz/QUERY` to:
`http://differentsite.com/?q=sea:r.ch QUERY`

I am having trouble with adding the space in the above link...

Here is what I got so far in `root/sz/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://differentsite.com/?q=sea:r.ch%20$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sz/(.+)$ "http://differentsite.com/?q=sea:r.ch $1" [L,QSA,NE,R]
```